# Sending Variables using javascript using HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, post

I have an issue with some software at work.  Normally we have training material produced and then hosted within an LMS, but on this occasion I have to get the course results sent to another server (using Articulate Storyline 360 and trying to POST to a php file on another webserver).

I have managed to insert an event that triggers the javascript, which when I have tested it with a simple Alert Box, does correctly display the variables for FORENAME, SURNAME and DEPOT, using:

```
var player = GetPlayer();
alert("Welcome back, " + player.GetVar("Forename") + ".");
```

So I know the player.GetVar(variable) works.  My problem is getting the POST to work.  I know it isnt working because I am not getting the success popup after, and no data is going into the other end.

The php file I have waiting to receive the JSON is:

```
// takes raw data from the request 
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data);

//Get Variables
$forename = $json['Forename'];
$surname = $json['Surname'];
$depot = $json['Depot'];
```

I have zero experience with javascript, so I am really looking for someone to help me with this POST method, i have seen so many different ways on google, and none make much sense.  Thanks

The code I have on my POST is:

```
//get variables and build JSON
var player = GetPlayer();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Forename", player.GetVar("Forename"));
json.put("Surname", player.GetVar("Surname"));
json.put("Depot", player.GetVar("Depot"));

//post
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://flashpoint.flogas.co.uk/assurance/include/tasks/dmbctest.php");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        httpClient.execute(request);
    // handle response here...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
        alert("Details have been sent...");
    }
```

Comment: `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` and most of what follows is **Java**, not **JavaScript**. Find an HTTP tutorial for the language you are actually using.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the javascript fetch API:

```
const URL = "example.com" 
aforename = ....
asurname = ...
adepot = ...   

fetch(url,{
          method:"POST", // post method
          headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' // tells the server it is a json
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "Forename":aforename
              "Surname":asurname
              "Depot":adepot
          })
        })// This is defining the json that the server will receive

        // If you want a reply from the server...
        .then(res => res.json()) // Converts recieved data to a json
          .then(data => {
               // How you want to process the data
               
          })
```

Not sure if this is the right sota thing for the context but its worth being aware off